# Width of a flex item doesn't change when I use %

Tags: html, css

As far as I know, **width of a flex item adjusts to its content**(when `flex-direction: row;`).

Here you see, **the width of second `.item`** is too long even though I set the width of `h1` to 50%.

```css
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        border: 2px solid red;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      .item {
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
      .test {
        width: 50%;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
      <div class="item">
        <h1 class="test">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi,
          quo.
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

But when I use `px` instead of `%`, the result that I wanted comes out. (Please view it in a full page)

```css
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        border: 2px solid red;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      .item {
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
      .test {
        width: 400px;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
      <div class="item">
        <h1 class="test">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi,
          quo.
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I can't understand how `%` is calculated in the first code. Can somebody help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply the width on the `.item` element.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1 class="test">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, quo.
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not applying 50% to children (.item) but rather to (.test), which is not child of `display:flex`. Fix it and you'll get result!

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
}
.test {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
   <div class="item">
      <h1 class="test">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi,quo.         </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```